# How to run a python project on schedule (AWS, Heroku, etc)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I have a python etl project that I was to run on a schedule. I am a bit lost on where to start. I have seen some tutorials using Heroku and AWS Lambda, but these were all single script files. My main script references multiple packages that are all in the same project directory. Am I able to deploy the entire project and have it run the main script on a schedule? If so, what tools/services should I be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

See [Lambda Scheduled Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduledevents-example.html). You can create a Lambda function and direct AWS Lambda to execute it on a regular schedule. You can specify a fixed rate (for example, execute a Lambda function every hour or 15 minutes), or you can specify a Cron expression.

Be aware of the [Lambda package size limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html).